# In Perl, how can filter all log files in a directory, and extract interesting lines?

Tags: perl, grep

I'm trying to select only the .log files in my directory and then search in those files for the word "unbound" and print the entire line into a new output file with the same name as the log file (`number###.log`) but with a `.txt` extension. This is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

  use strict;
  use warnings;

  my $path = $ARGV[0];
  my $outpath = $ARGV[1];
  my @files;
  my $files;

  opendir(DIR,$path) or die "$!";
  @files = grep { /\.log$/} readdir(DIR);


  my @out;
  my $out;
  opendir(OUT,$outpath) or die "$!";

  my $line;
  foreach $files (@files) {
  open (FILE, "$files");
  my @line = <FILE>;
  my $regex = Unbound;
  open (OUT, ">>$out");
  print grep {$line =~ /$regex/ } <>;
   } 
  close OUT;
  close FILE;

  closedir(DIR);
  closedir (OUT);
```

I'm a beginner, and I don't really know how to create a new text file with the acquired output.

Comment: `perl -ne' if (/unbound/) { open my $out, ">>", $ARGV . ".txt" or die $!; print $out $_; }' *.log` perhaps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Few things I'd suggest to improve this code:

- declare your loop iterators within the loop. `foreach my $file ( @files ) {`
- use 3 arg `open`: `open ( my $input_fh, "<", $filename );`
- use `glob` rather than `opendir` then `grep`. `foreach my $file ( <$path/*.txt> ) {`
- `grep` is good for extracting things into arrays. Your `grep` reads the whole file to print it, which isn't necessary. Doesn't matter much if the file is short though.
- `perltidy` is great for reformatting code.
- you're opening 'OUT' to a directory path (I think?) which isn't going to work.
- `$outpath` isn't, it's a file. You need to do something different to output to different files. `opendir` isn't really valid to an output.
- because you're using `opendir` that's actually giving you filenames - not full paths. So you might be in the wrong place to actually open the files. Prepending the path name, doing a `chdir` are possible solutions. But that's one of the reasons I like `glob` because it returns a path as well.

So with that in mind - how about:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;

#Extract paths
my $input_path  = $ARGV[0];
my $output_path = $ARGV[1];

#Error if paths are invalid. 
unless (defined $input_path
    and -d $input_path
    and defined $output_path
    and -d $output_path )
{
    die "Usage: $0 <input_path> <output_path>\n";
}

foreach my $filename (<$input_path/*.log>) {

   # extract the 'name' bit of the filename. 
   # be slightly careful with this - it's based 
   # on an assumption which isn't always true. 
   # File::Spec is a more powerful way of accomplishing this.
   # but should grab 'number####' from /path/to/file/number####.log
   my $output_file = basename ( $filename, '.log' );

   #open input and output filehandles. 
   open( my $input_fh, "<", $filename ) or die $!;
   open( my $output_fh, ">", "$output_path/$output_file.txt" ) or die $!;

   print "Processing $filename -> $output_path/$output_file.txt\n";

   #iterate input, extracting into $line
   while ( my $line = <$input_fh> ) {
        #check if $line matches your RE. 
        if ( $line =~ m/Unbound/ ) {
            #write it to output. 
            print {$output_fh} $line;
        }
   }
   #tidy up our filehandles. Although technically, they'll 
   #close automatically because they leave scope
   close($output_fh);
   close($input_fh);
}
```

Comment: Why `$filename =~ m,/(\w+).log$,` when there are umpteen ways to actually do it correctly?! See [Construct the path to a file in the same directory as the current script](http://perlmaven.com/path-to-file-in-the-same-directory-as-script), and [int main in C and hard coded directory separators in Perl](http://www.nu42.com/2014/12/int-main-in-c-and-hard-coded-directory.html), [More adventures in test failures](http://www.nu42.com/2014/11/more-adventures-in-test-failures.html), and my other [assorted rants](http://www.nu42.com/2014/11/tests-failing-due-to-path-separators.html).

Comment: Well, I could use all sorts of justifications, but in all honesty - because I've not been caught out by doing it that way yet.

Comment: @Sobrique I really appreciate all your comments! I am learning so much. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Updated to use `File::Basename` as a less bad example :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a script that takes advantage of [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny). Now, at this stage of your learning process, you are probably better off understanding [@Sobrique's solution](/a/28633730/100754), but using modules such as [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) or [Path::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class) will make it easier to write these one off scripts more quickly, and correctly.

Also, I didn't really test this script, so watch out for bugs.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Path::Tiny;

run(\@ARGV);

sub run {
    my $argv = shift;
    unless (@$argv == 2) {
        die "Need source and destination paths\n";
    }
    my $it = path($argv->[0])->realpath->iterator({
        recurse => 0,
        follow_symlinks => 0,
    });
    my $outdir = path($argv->[1])->realpath;

    while (my $path = $it->()) {
        next unless -f $path;
        next unless $path =~ /[.]log\z/;

        my $logfh = $path->openr;
        my $outfile = $outdir->child($path->basename('.log') . '.txt');
        my $outfh;

        while (my $line = <$logfh>) {
            next unless $line =~ /Unbound/;
            unless ($outfh) {
                $outfh = $outfile->openw;
            }
            print $outfh $line;
        }
        close $outfh
            or die "Cannot close output '$outfile': $!";
    }
}
```

#### Notes

- [realpath](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#realpath) will croak if the path provided does not exist.
- Similarly for [openr](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#openr) and [openw](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#openw).
- I am reading input files line-by-line to keep the memory footprint of the program independent of the sizes of input files.
- I do not open the output file until I know I have a match to print to.
- When matching a file extension using a regular expression pattern, keep in mind that `\n` is a valid character in Unix file names, and the `$` anchor *will* match it.